# Collecting multiple flows into one

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am collecting data from datastore in flows in nested launch{}.

```
   viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { 
                launch { 
                    DataStore.userName.collect {
                       // it emits string value
                        Log.e(TAG, it )
                    }
                }
                launch {
                    DataStore.userPhone.collect {
                       // it emits string value
                        Log.e(TAG, it )
                    }
                }
                launch {
                    DataStore.userAddress.collect {
                       // it emits string value
                        Log.e(TAG, it )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there a better way to collect flows in fragments ? Like collecting all data in single launch{} block.

Comment: Use could use combine : `fun <T1, T2, T3, R> combine(flow: Flow<T1>, flow2: Flow<T2>, flow3: Flow<T3>, transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3) -> R): Flow<R>`. So usage here `combine(DataStore.userName, DataStore.userPhone, DataStore.userAddress, ::Triple).onEach{ (name, phone, address) -> .... }.launchIn(scope)` - consider adding this as a convenience method in the `DataStore`.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to combine all flows like this:

```kotlin
combine(DataStore.userName, DataStore.userPhone, DataStore.userAddress) { userName, userPhone, userAddress ->
    // Operate on these values
}
```

Another option can be to use `launchIn` which launches the collection of flow in provided coroutine scope.

```kotlin
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { 
    DataStore.userName.onEach { userName ->
        // ...
    }.launchIn(this)

    DataStore.userPhone.onEach { userPhone ->
        // ...
    }.launchIn(this)

    DataStore.userAddress.onEach { userAddress ->
        // ...
    }.launchIn(this)
}
```

`launchIn` is just a shorthand for `scope.launch { flow.collect() }`.

Comment: To clarify, combine() emits a new combination of the current values from all source flows, whenever a single source flow emits a new value. This may be wanted behaviour, but can lead to multiple redundant operations. For unique combinations like user data, zip() might be the better option.

Comment: @nulldroid Can we use zip with multiple flows? From what I remember we can only zip two flows at a time, `flow1.zip(flow2) { a,b -> }`

Comment: Oops, somehow I forgot about that. You are correct, zip works only with two flows out of the box.  You would need to do a nested zip in this case.
flow1.zip(flow2) { a,b -> }.zip(flow3) {ab, c -> }

Comment: Zip will only emit when all flows change .. so if a user changes their address, for example, the latest address change won't be observed using the zip operator. Also chained zips means it's implicitly dependent on the previous zip operation which can lead to other problems. Combine is the correct operator, which combines the latest of all flows, regardless if they are updated independently.

Comment: All the options are appreciated , I think I will go with combining the three flows. It seems to solve my problem