# How to run multiple collects in single launch block (kotlin coroutines)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there some neat way how do something like launchAll, or collectAll (but not merge)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just like this [stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69787697/collecting-multiple-flows-into-one) or [here in github](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1933) which lead me to [this documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#launching-flow), combination of onEach and launchIn is probably preferred way.

There is my extension to make it more clear (about collecting):

```
/**
 * Collects given receiver flow in given scope.
 *
 * Replaces several launch blocks with single collect call.
 *
 * Simplify onEach{ block() }.launchIn(coroutineScope).
 */
fun <T> Flow<T>.collectIn(scope: CoroutineScope, context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, action: suspend (T) -> Unit): Job =
onEach(action).launchIn(scope, context)

/**
 * Collect.kt variant of [launchIn] with ability to specify context to launch in.
 */
fun <T> Flow<T>.launchIn(scope: CoroutineScope, context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext): Job = scope.launch(context) {
collect() // tail-call
}
```

Comment: There's a `flowOn` operator for specifying context.

Comment: Note that you still perform `launch()` for each flow. The only difference is that you obfuscate your code (personal opinion).

Comment: I'm assuming the above functions are just to illustrate the concept. In practice, the above functions should not exist since they obfuscate the operators. You should use `onEach { }.flowOn().launchIn()` in your actual project for clear code.